# method_exists returning false

Tags: php, oop, methods

I am new to php oop so please bear with me...

I have a method in a class called regions that is not returning a result and when I use `method_exists` it say it does not exist.  I can not see what I am doing wrong.

This is the class:

```
<?php
class SeniorMentor {
    public $regions;

    public function __toString() {

          $output = '';   
            $output .= $this->uid . "<br>";
            $output .= $this->fName . "<br>";
            $output .= $this->lName . "<br>";
            $output .= $this->email . "<br>";
            return $output;
    }

    public function regions() {
        $uid = 120;
        include 'classes/con.php';  
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT region, region_id FROM regions WHERE uid = :uid');
    $stmt->execute(array('uid' => $this->uid));

    while($row2 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR)) {
     $regions = $row2;
     return $regions;
        }           
    }
}
```

This is the script calling it:

```
<?php

include 'classes/con.php';
include 'classes/SeniorMentor.php';

$uid = 120;

$seniorMentor = new SeniorMentor;

echo $seniorMentor->regions($uid);

var_dump(method_exists($seniormentor,'regions'));

$sq = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM primary_profile", PDO::FETCH_INTO, $seniorMentor);

while($row = $sq->fetch()) {

    echo "$row <br/>";
}

?>
```

Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP Variables are Case-Sensitive. This means the `$seniorMentor` and `$seniormentor` are two completely different variables.

```
var_dump(method_exists($seniormentor,'regions'));
```

Should be:

```
var_dump(method_exists($seniorMentor,'regions'));
```

In most cases, I would recommend sticking with a standard [naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) to avoid this issue. The two most common are Camel Case and Delimiter Case.

Eg: Camel case `$seniorMentor`

Eg: Delimiter Case `$senior_mentor`

Comment: Thanks for catching that... do you have any idea why regions is not returning any data?  I am not sure if this needs to be resubmitted as a new question or not...

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities with that question. I would consider taking steps to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling that from `trait`, check the caller class.

Comment: Thank you T.  this was so long ago I can't even remember what i did to resolve it but thanks for the suggestion